# What happens when redirecting unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I understand that `unique_ptr` is a single owner of some object and it deallocates that object when it goes out of scope. What I don't understand is the following situation:

```
unique_ptr<int> p(new int(1));
p = unique_ptr<int>(new int(2));
```

What happens with the first object `new int(1)` if `p` is redirected to another memory location `new int(2)` (since `p` can own only one of those)?

Comment: It's lost, gone forever, but guaranteed to be cleaned up properly. If the type isn't a POD, its destructor will be called (unless some custom deallocator was used).

Comment: That's what I don't understand. Who will clean him up properly since he is not owned by nobody?

Comment: `unique_ptr` is an object like any other, with a constructor and destructor. When `p = unique_ptr` is called, the destructor for `p` will be called which will clean up the memory.

Comment: @Tas: No, `p`'s assignment operator is what's cleaning up the memory there. A destructor is getting called, but it's not `p`'s destructor, but the destructor of the temporary `unique_ptr`, after it is moved from.

Comment: Indeed, this kind of safety and sanity is _the entire purpose_ of `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`unique_ptr` destroys the object it owns when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed *or reseated*. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct T {
    T(int x) : x(x) {
        cout << "T(" << x << ")\n";
    }
    ~T() {
        cout << "~T(" << x << ")\n";
    }
    int x;
};

int main() {
    unique_ptr<T> p(new T(1));
    p = unique_ptr<T>(new T(2));
}
```

This will print:

- `T(1)` when the first object is created.
- `T(2)` when the second object is created.
- `~T(1)` when the first object is freed by the assignment operator of `p`.
- `~T(2)` when the second object is freed by the destructor of `p`.

Comment: If `T(1)` is destroyed by assignment operator of `p` what happens in this case? `unique_ptr<T> p(new T(1)); unique_ptr<T> p2(new T(2)); p2 = move(p);` Who destroyed `new T(2)`?

Comment: @Tracer: `p2` did when it was assigned to.

Comment: @Tracer: the move assignment operator of `p2` must destroy `new T(2)` before moving `new T(1)` into `p2` from `p`.

Comment: @JonPurdy: I don't know if that is accurate. I'm wondering whether it would be legal (and efficient) to implement that assignment as a swap, since `p` is moved from.

Comment: @MSalters: I think you could implement it as a swap followed by a release, as long as the swap is also `noexcept`. §20.7.1¶3 says “Let the notation `u.p` denote the pointer stored by `u`, and let `u.d` denote the associated deleter. Upon request, `u` can reset (replace) `u.p` and `u.d` with another pointer and deleter, but must properly dispose of its owned object via the associated deleter before such replacement is considered completed.”

Answer (score 2):

`unique_ptr` is defined to make sure the first int is properly deallocated, so it calls a `delete` on it, freeing the reserved memory.

It is somewhat identical to this code:

```
int* p = new int(1);
delete p;
p = new int(2);
```

What happens in detail is this:

- You create a new Integer using `new int(1)`.
- You pass the pointer to this new int to the just created instance of `unique_ptr` named `p`. This is an object that just stores the pointer for the moment.
- You create a second int using `new int(2)`.
- You pass this pointer to a new `unique_ptr` using `unique_ptr<int>(new int(2))`, this is a temporary instance of unique_ptr (we will see why in a second) and it stores the pointer to the second int.
- You assign the temporary object to `p`. Now the assignment operator is defined to delete the previously owned object (the first int) and take ownership of the object owned by the assigned unique_ptr (the second int). An implementation is shown below. At this point `p` owns the second int, the first int is deleted and the temporary owns no object anymore (holding the `nullptr`).
- As last part the temporary `unique_ptr` goes out of scope, since we never gave it a name or stored a reference to it, so its destructor gets called. But it only holds the `nullptr` anyway.

So the more detailed equivalent using raw pointers would be something like this:

```
int* p = new int(1);  //create an int
{
    int* tmp = new int(2);  //create second int
    int* del = p; //we need to delete this (first int)

    //take ownership of the temporary (second int)
    p = tmp; 
    tmp=nullptr;

    //delete the old object (first int)
    delete del;
}  //tmp and del go out of scope here, but tmp holds the nullptr and del is deleted
//first int is deleted, p points to the second int here
```

*Edit for Tracer:*
This is the implementation used by visual studio (the comment is part of `<memory>` as well):

```
typedef unique_ptr<_Ty> _Myt;

_Myt& operator=(_Myt&& _Right) _NOEXCEPT
{   // assign by moving _Right
    if (this != &_Right)
    {   // different, do the move
        reset(_Right.release());
        this->get_deleter() = _STD forward<_Dx>(_Right.get_deleter());
    }
return (*this);
}

void reset(pointer _Ptr = pointer()) _NOEXCEPT
 {  // establish new pointer
    pointer _Old = get();
    this->_Myptr() = _Ptr;
    if (_Old != pointer())
        this->get_deleter()(_Old);
 }
```

Comment: Switching pointers? Are you sure about that? Is there anything in the C++ standard that supports that statement?

Comment: @Tracer: i mixed it up with shared_ptr. In the implementation of shared_ptr that is shipped with visual studio a temporary shared_ptr is copy-constructed in the assignment operator. Then the current pointer is switched with the temporary. When the temporary goes out of scope, the shared_ptr itself holds the assigned value and the temporary holds the old value, decreasing its reference count/ destructing the object. But since this question is about unique_ptr, i updated the answer accordingly.